# Set file description in apache2

Tags: apache-2.2, file-sharing

In the default file listing page (mod_autoindex) on apache2 (OS X), there is a column marked "description". Does anyone know of how you actually set what appears here? All of mine are blank, as are most of the ones on other servers that I see.

Sorry if this is really obvious but I can't find the answer anywhere else, including apache's docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Apache's docs on mod_autoindex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_autoindex.html) reveal two ways to set descriptions.

First, you can use [`AddDescription`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_autoindex.html#adddescription) to set individual descriptions for files or groups of files by partial match.

Second, you can set [`IndexOptions +ScanHTMLTitles`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexoptions) and Apache will use the `<title>` of each HTML document as its `Description`. This is CPU and disk intensive though.

Descriptions given by `AddDescription` take precedence.